# How to handle an iframe's popstate event or disable browser's back button on an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, browser, back-button, popstate

I'm trying to use soundcloud's html5 widget on my web site and it loads the widget inside an iframe. When track is finished i load another url by using their [javascript api](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) to the widget and it reloads iframe as i see. Then browser's back button becomes enable. When i press the back button it loads the widget to previous url. But also i'm using ajax on my page and the back button throws a monkey wrench into works. I wonder if there is a way to prevent iframe to push history or handle operation when pressing the back button. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

this works fine in all browser for disable back button

```
         history.pushState(null, null, url);
         window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
            history.pushState(null, null, url);
        });
```